# Не выводится изображение в активности

Tags: android, графика, 2d

Пытаюсь вывести изображение в приложении в LinearLayout, задаю фон красным, но в эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве при запуске активности Layout, отображается черным прямоугольником. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю неправильно.

Код активности:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

LinearLayout draw2dLayout = findViewById(R.id.draw2d);
draw2dLayout.addView(new Draw2D(this));
}

public void Back(View view){finish();}

}
```

код класса который должен выводить изображение:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Draw2D extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

public static float x;
public static Paint paint;
public float width = 30;
public float height = 45;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
Thread gameThread;
boolean firstTime = true;
public static float y;
Canvas canvas;
int time = 500;
Mouse mouse;


public Draw2D(Context context) {
super(context);
surfaceHolder = getHolder();
paint = new Paint();
gameThread = null;
gameThread = new Thread(this);
gameThread.start();
}

public void run(){
Draw();
Sleep();

}

protected void Draw() {
if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
if(firstTime){
firstTime = false;
x = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().width()/width;
y = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().height()/height;
}
canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
mouse.draw(paint, canvas);
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
}

public void Sleep(){
try {
Thread.sleep(time);
} catch (InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}


}
}
```

Если закомментировать эти строки, то все фон в Layoute отображается тот который задаю в разметке:

```
LinearLayout draw2dLayout = findViewById(R.id.draw2d);
draw2dLayout.addView(new Draw2D(this));
```

Comment: Дело в том, что `SurfaceView` изначально не прозрачен. Я не припомню как это можно исправить, поищите в этом направлении, либо в методе `Draw()` закрашивайте всё фоновым цветом, а потом рисуйте остальное.

Comment: Да, точно фон нужно закрашивать методом setBackgroundColor(),  как выяснилось по умолчанию он идет черный.